How to achieve the parallel mixed layout of pictures and texts?
I want to achieve the layout in which the text is on the left, while the figure is put properly on the right. To be specificly, as the figure shown below, I want to achieve that:

The first two lines[main of the problem] are not wrapped, and it extend to the right of the page
The two sub-question be assigned at the left of the next two lines
The tikzpicture be the right of the two sub-question
All parts be center vertically for better looking
I hope that the whole problem could be a whole widgets, which means that it can be put into env like tcolorbox freely

I consult the docs of wrapfigure and picinpar, but it didn't perform well with bad box and indent which actually confused me. Then after some further exploration, I found that using minipage may help, but it maybe couldn't put all problem together(I mean the two minipages is seperate of the first two lines, should I put them into an outer environment?).
I wonder what is the best practice to achieve the result of the layout of left text and right figure or table? Thx!!
Here below is the mwe and result.
\documentclass[12pt]{ctexart}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fbox}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{picinpar}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    19.(本小题满分$12$分)在斜三棱柱$ABC$ \textbullet $A_1B_1C_1$中, $\triangle ABC$是等腰直角三角形, $AB=BC$,$AC=2\sqrt{3}$, 平面$ACC_1A_1\perp$底面$ABC$, $A_1B=AA_1=2$.\\
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{6cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[help lines] (-1,-1.5) grid (5,1.5);
            \draw (0,0) sin (1,1) cos (2,0) sin (3,-1) cos (4,0);
            \draw (0,1) cos (1,0) sin (2,-1) cos (3,0) sin (4,1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    (1)证明: $A_1B \perp AC$;\\
    (2)求二面角 $A_1-BC-C_1$的正弦值.\\
\end{tcolorbox}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{window}[1,r,{\mbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
                            \draw[help lines] (-1,-1.5) grid (5,1.5);
                            \draw (0,0) sin (1,1) cos (2,0) sin (3,-1) cos (4,0);
                            \draw (0,1) cos (1,0) sin (2,-1) cos (3,0) sin (4,1);
                        \end{tikzpicture}}},{}]
        19.(本小题满分$12$分)在斜三棱柱$ABC$ \textbullet $A_1B_1C_1$中, $\triangle ABC$是等腰直角三角形, $AB=BC$,$AC=2\sqrt{3}$, 平面$ACC_1A_1\perp$底面$ABC$, $A_1B=AA_1=2$.\\
        (1)证明: $A_1B \perp AC$;\\
        (2)求二面角 $A_1-BC-C_1$的正弦值.\\
    \end{window}
\end{tcolorbox}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    19.(本小题满分$12$分)在斜三棱柱$ABC$ \textbullet $A_1B_1C_1$中, $\triangle ABC$是等腰直角三角形, $AB=BC$,$AC=2\sqrt{3}$, 平面$ACC_1A_1\perp$底面$ABC$, $A_1B=AA_1=2$.\\
    \begin{minipage}[p]{.65\textwidth}
        (1)证明: $A_1B \perp AC$;\\
        (2)求二面角 $A_1-BC-C_1$的正弦值.\\
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[p]{.4\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[help lines] (-1,-1.5) grid (5,1.5);
            \draw (0,0) sin (1,1) cos (2,0) sin (3,-1) cos (4,0);
            \draw (0,1) cos (1,0) sin (2,-1) cos (3,0) sin (4,1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}


------------seperate line of the origin problem------------
Actually use the counter instead of typing it manually is more elegant, but for this specific problem, it is impossible to add another question, in other word, the number of sub-questions is fixed at 2. If the number turns 5 or more, I am glad to use \item, while when I confront the only 2 items, in my opioion it's inconvenience for more 2 lines.
(1) question1
(2) question2

\begin{enumerate}
\item question1
\item question2
\end{enumerate}

And I know I actually should listen to yr sincere advice, but I wonder the reason of "if there is only 2 fixed items(with no requirement of  reference and modification) we should still use \itemize env." thx!
As for the 'wrap',what I mean is whether the line should be broken to the next line. To extend the problem, we know that when we TeX some math questions with figure, the layout have kinds of types.
In different length and scale combinations of questions and figure, shown as below, is the minipage always perform best? I think the indent of short subquestions is a little big. Is there any better advice?


if needed, the code of additional layouts is as below.
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\section{Problem}
The problem consists of the following three parts:
\begin{itemize}
    \item main question
    \item sub-questions
    \item figure
\end{itemize}

What's the practice to assign their position properly in the page?(use \char 92 tcolorbox is because I get used to put the question into the box)

\subsection{Long main question,short sub-questions}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    I'm the long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long main question.\\
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item short sub-question1
            \item short sub-question2
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{2cm}
    \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        I'm the long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long main question.\\
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item short sub-question1
            \item short sub-question2
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{2cm}
    \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
    \end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}
\subsection{Short main question,short sub-questions}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    I'm the short short short short short short short short short short main question.\\
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item short sub-question1
            \item short sub-question2
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{2cm}
    \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        I'm the short short short short short short short short short short main question.
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item short sub-question1
            \item short sub-question2
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{2cm}
    \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
    \end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}


\subsection{Long main question,long sub-questions}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    I'm the long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long main question.\\
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long sub-question1
            \item long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long sub-question2
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{2cm}
    \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    I'm the long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long main question.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long sub-question1
        \item long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long sub-question2
    \end{enumerate}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
\end{tcolorbox}

\subsection{long figure}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{minipage}{.65\textwidth}
        I'm the short main question.
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item short sub-question1
            \item short sub-question2
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}

        \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=6cm]{example-image}
    \end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}


Don't try to put a wrapfigure inside a tcolorbox. Use tcolorbox's side by side option instead an put each thing into one bit of the box. This will put the figure in the 'lower' part of the box, but side by side means it will actually be on the right rather than below.

I'm not sure what you mean about the top lines not wrapping. They didn't extend beyond the confines of the box for me?

sorry, I didn't paraphrase the wrap clearly. I just design the layout of the main question and sub-questions.  I will add some illustration to the question.

Since you are already using tcolorbox, I would keep using it. There is no reason you cannot nest tcolorboxes (at least, no general reason). Split the main box into upper and lower and the lower box into left and right. If you want to adjust the format e.g. alignment or padding, the manual documents the options well. (It is very long, but finding the relevant bit is the only thing which takes time, so just search.)
Don't number things manually in LaTeX - always use counters e.g. lists, numbered boxes etc. - and don't end lines with \\  except in special environments.
\documentclass[12pt]{ctexart}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\NewTColorBox{simplesidebyside}{ O {} }% add sidebyside for sidebyside boxes etc. (intended for 'invisible' boxes within tcolorboxes)
{
  empty,
  size=minimal,
  top=.25mm,
  bottom=.25mm,
  sidebyside,
  #1,
}
\newlist{boxlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[boxlist]{label=(\arabic*),nosep}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[lower separated=false]
  % if this is incremented in your document, use a counter - don't specify numbering manually
  19.(本小题满分$12$分)在斜三棱柱$ABC$ \textbullet $A_1B_1C_1$中, $\triangle ABC$是等腰直角三角形, $AB=BC$,$AC=2\sqrt{3}$, 平面$ACC_1A_1\perp$底面$ABC$, $A_1B=AA_1=2$.
  \tcblower
  \begin{simplesidebyside}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[help lines] (-1,-1.5) grid (5,1.5);
      \draw (0,0) sin (1,1) cos (2,0) sin (3,-1) cos (4,0);
      \draw (0,1) cos (1,0) sin (2,-1) cos (3,0) sin (4,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \tcblower
    % ditto
    \begin{boxlist}
      \item 证明: $A_1B \perp AC$;
      \item 求二面角 $A_1-BC-C_1$的正弦值.
    \end{boxlist}
  \end{simplesidebyside}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[lower separated=false]
  % if this is incremented in your document, use a counter - don't specify numbering manually
  19.(本小题满分$12$分)在斜三棱柱$ABC$ \textbullet $A_1B_1C_1$中, $\triangle ABC$是等腰直角三角形, $AB=BC$,$AC=2\sqrt{3}$, 平面$ACC_1A_1\perp$底面$ABC$, $A_1B=AA_1=2$.
  \tcblower
  \begin{simplesidebyside}
    % ditto
    \begin{boxlist}
      \item 证明: $A_1B \perp AC$;
      \item 求二面角 $A_1-BC-C_1$的正弦值.
    \end{boxlist}
    \tcblower
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[help lines] (-1,-1.5) grid (5,1.5);
      \draw (0,0) sin (1,1) cos (2,0) sin (3,-1) cos (4,0);
      \draw (0,1) cos (1,0) sin (2,-1) cos (3,0) sin (4,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{simplesidebyside}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[lower separated=false,sidebyside]
  % if this is incremented in your document, use a counter - don't specify numbering manually
  19.(本小题满分$12$分)在斜三棱柱$ABC$ \textbullet $A_1B_1C_1$中, $\triangle ABC$是等腰直角三角形, $AB=BC$,$AC=2\sqrt{3}$, 平面$ACC_1A_1\perp$底面$ABC$, $A_1B=AA_1=2$.
  % ditto
  \begin{boxlist}
    \item 证明: $A_1B \perp AC$;
    \item 求二面角 $A_1-BC-C_1$的正弦值.
  \end{boxlist}
  \tcblower
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines] (-1,-1.5) grid (5,1.5);
    \draw (0,0) sin (1,1) cos (2,0) sin (3,-1) cos (4,0);
    \draw (0,1) cos (1,0) sin (2,-1) cos (3,0) sin (4,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}


